# Problema al subir un archivo a Git, sube el archivo pero no me deja visualizar una carpeta

Tags: git, react-native, git-push, git-commit

La carpeta que tiene la flecha hacia la izquierda no me deja visualizar, no puedo entrar a la carpeta.
Que esta pasando que no me deja entrar a la carpeta y como puedo solucionarlo? gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La carpeta que no te deja visualizar es un acceso directo, si te fijas en el icono de la carpeta es diferente a las normales que si puedes visualizar.

Lo que tienes que hacer para arreglarlo es eliminar ese acceso directo desde tu máquina y hacer una nueva copia del contenido de la carpeta que no puedes visualizar. Solo nota que en esta ocasión no sea un acceso directo.

Por lo regular puedes saber si la carpeta es un acceso directo o no porque git no te deja agregar carpetas vacías a un commit. Si te deja agregar una carpeta vacía, lo más seguro es que de nuevo tu carpeta es un acceso directo, de lo contrario previo a hacer el commit podrás ver el contenido dentro.